# Check the continuity of a function of two variables

Tags: limits, functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I've been trying to check the continuity of the following function:

$$ f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
    \frac {(x-1)(y-4)^2}{(x-1)^2+\sin(y-4)}      & \quad \text{(x,y) } \ne \text{ (1,4)}\\
    0  & \quad \text{(x,y) } = \text{ (1,4)}
  \end{cases} $$

I've tried calculating the following $lim$ , as $t = x-1$ , and $ z = y-4 $ :

$$ \lim_{{(t,z)\to(0,0)}}{ \frac {tz^2}{t^2+\sin(z)}} $$

I've tried choosing different paths: $ t=z$ and $t=z^2$
but both gave me the same result - $0$ .

I'm not sure how to prove or disprove that the limit is $0$ .

I'd appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Can derive the limit for the given trajectory?

Comment: If you mean using L'Hôpital's rule, then yes.

Comment: as an alternative to l'Hopital (I suggest to don't use that if it is not necessary), we can observe that $$\arcsin (t^5-t^2)=-t^2+o(t^4)$$ or use standard limits $$\frac {t(\arcsin (t^5-t^2))^2}{t^2+t^5-t^2}=\frac {(\arcsin (t^5-t^2))^2}{(t^5-t^2)^2}\frac{t(t^5-t^2)^2}{t^5}\to 1$$

Comment: @gimusi, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Since you are new here, FYI recall that here on MSE you can take into consideration to accept an answer among the given as described here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $z=\arcsin (t^5-t^2)\to 0$

$$\frac {tz^2}{t^2+\sin(z)}=\frac {t(\arcsin (t^5-t^2))^2}{t^2+t^5-t^2}\to 1$$

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot! :-)

Comment: @imqueeny You are welcome!